# Error populating a jQuery datable with a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

```
                       var resultTable = $('#templateRegArea').DataTable({

                            "columns": [
                                { data: "ID" },
                                { data: "Name" },
                                { data: "Description" },
                            ],
                        });
                        resultTable.rows.add(response.d).draw();
                        dataSet = response.d;
```

I am trying to bind a table 'templateRegArea' with the values present in "response.d" in a Jquery datatable.

**response.d** 
[image]

I have attached the value of "response". The problem I am facing is the data are not getting loaded into the table.
HELP :(

Comment: If you're wondering why you're getting downvoted then know that this is not a valid question. Change your question and ask a specific question.

Comment: Now if you know the answer, Kindly help

Comment: can you please post entire `response.d`. Actually `resultTable.rows.add` is for adding multiple lines which deals with an array. But in your JSON i don't see an array like `[ {...},{...} ]`

Comment: Still it should have populated a single row atleast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server-side script produces objects, when jQuery DataTables requires array of arrays or array of objects. For example:

```
{
    "d": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "John",
        "Description": "Test"
    }, {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Description": "Test"
    }]
}
```

When you correct the data structure as shown below, initialization code should be changed to:

```
var resultTable = $('#templateRegArea').DataTable({
   "data": response.d,
   "columns": [
      { "data": "ID" },
      { "data": "Name" },
      { "data": "Description" }
   ]
});
```

With the existing data structure you can use the code below, but that is only good for one data row.

```
var resultTable = $('#templateRegArea').DataTable({
   "data": [response.d],
   "columns": [
      { "data": "ID" },
      { "data": "Name" },
      { "data": "Description" }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: @Roneetshaw, added more details.

Comment: Thanks it worked. :) bdw any specific reason for this ?